# Why does Bunifu controls shows error on this.Close()

Tags: c#, bunifu

**Goal:**

I have a simple goal, close the form.

**Code:**

**This is Bunifu button:**

[image]

```
private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

**This is normal button:**

[image]

```
private void normal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

**Detail:**

This is what happens when clicking the normal button:

Form closes without errors.

Whereas, clicking the buniful button shows me this error:

[image]

**Question:**

Why does the Bunifu button throws me this error? I have not got a clue to what the error means. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that happens because bunifu buttons have some methods after closing the form like change color on hover etc.

You may try this below codes

```
private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bunifuFlatButton1.Enabled = false;
this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Intresting.. What does the Enabled do? Between `true` and `false`?